# Как изменить (UPDATE) данные при их запросе (SELECT)?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Есть исходная таблица (fruits):

```
ID |  TITLE   |  COLOR   |  COUNT
___|_____________________________
1  |  Banana  |  Yellow  |  0
2  |  Lemon   |  Yellow  |  0
3  |  Apple   |  Green   |  0
4  |  Orange  |  Orange  |  0
5  |  Pear    |  Yellow  |  0
```

Как мне изменить значение `COUNT` при запросе:

```
"SELECT title FROM fruits WHERE color = 'Yellow' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2";
```

Т.е. должны измениться на единицу два случайно выбранных фрукта:

```
ID |  TITLE   |  COLOR   |  COUNT
___|_____________________________
1  |  Banana  |  Yellow  |  1
2  |  Lemon   |  Yellow  |  0
3  |  Apple   |  Green   |  0
4  |  Orange  |  Orange  |  0
5  |  Pear    |  Yellow  |  1
```

Получилось написать следующее:

```
"UPDATE fruits 
    SET count = (count + 1) 
  WHERE title 
     IN (SELECT title 
           FROM fruits 
          WHERE color = 'Yellow' 
       ORDER BY RANDOM() 
          LIMIT 2)"
```

Но при таком запросе я не могу работать с выбранными записями.

Comment: измениться в таблице? или просто в результате select?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis нужно выбрать несколько записей и , например, вывести их на экран, но при этом их значение `count` в таблице должно поменяться, выводить и использовать его я не буду

Comment: тогда это 2 разных операции в sqlite это можно решить только 2 разными операциями - сначала update, затем select. как вариант - добавьте в таблицу метку для обновленных записей и по ней выбирайте последние обновленные записи

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis спасибо, без двух операций не обойтись, тоже уже об этом подумал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для себя решил это следующим способом:

- сначала выполняю запрос не только названий, но и их `ID`;

`"SELECT id, title FROM fruits WHERE color = 'Yellow' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2";`

- сохраняю список ID, например, `IDs = "1, 2"`;
- использую его для обновления данных во втором запросе.

`"UPDATE fruits SET count = (count + 1) WHERE id IN (" + IDs + ");"`